# Conversion of variable characters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I use this statement within a query to  get a blank result with a WHEN/THEN statement but keep getting the following error message:

" The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value." Below is the statement:

CASE

```
WHEN (A.APRDAT+'-'+A.APRBAT)= 01/01/1800
THEN ' '
ELSE
Convert(NVARchar(20),A.APRDAT)+'-'+Convert(NVARchar(20),A.APRBAT)
```

END AS AUTH_ID,

Could I get some assistance in getting this to work as design..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Date literals need to be in single quotes, and you'll need to `CONVERT` the string result:

```
WHEN CONVERT(DATETIME,A.APRDAT+'-'+A.APRBAT) = '01/01/1800'
THEN ' '
ELSE
Convert(NVARchar(20),A.APRDAT)+'-'+Convert(NVARchar(20),A.APRBAT)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But still getting the same error message. Here is what I have in there now: CASE
WHEN CONVERT(DATETIME,A.APRDAT+'-'+A.APRBAT) = '01/01/1800'
THEN ' '
ELSE
Convert(NVARchar(20),A.APRDAT)+'-'+Convert(NVARchar(20),A.APRBAT) END AS AUTH_ID,

Comment: Where are you storing the result?  In a `DATETIME` field or variable?

Comment: I think the issue may be because APRBAT is a time field and APRDAT is a Date field so it's erroring out 
converting the varchar value 'Jan  1 1800 12:00AM' to data type int.  The AUTH_ID is a combination of both fields...

Comment: So what is `{date} + '-' + {time}` supposed to represent?  Sounds like you may be better off using date/time functions rather than string parsing/conversion.

Comment: THE  {date} + '-' + {time}  represent the field combination to form the auth_id output. so I can try your idea if u can give me sample